# Getting NoMethodError ---> undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-1.9

I am totally new to Ruby and while testing some changes , I'm getting the error below: Can somebody please highlight what does the below mean ?

`undefined method [] for nil:NilClass`

```
adapterClient = Service.get_client(
      ADAPTER_SERVICE_NAME,
      service_info['server'],
      service_info['port'],
      service_info['path']
    )
```

Comment: paste the complete error.

Answer (score 0):

When you see `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`, it means:

> Hey! You have a value that is `nil` followed by `[...]`, but `nil` doesn't
>   have this method.

In your case, it could be `service_info['server']`, `service_info['port']` or `service_info['path']` is `nil`.